# How to copy from Parent table to Child Table with 1 column dividing into 3 different column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table column like following

```
Name
a
b
c
d
e
f
```

Now I want to Divide this column into 3 columns like as

```
Name1 | Name2 | Name3
a     | c     | f
b     | d     | e
```

How will the SQL Query for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On MySQL 8+, you could use `ROW_NUMBER` for this purpose:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT Name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Name) - 1 rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT
    MAX(CASE WHEN FLOOR(rn / 2) = 0 THEN Name END) AS Name1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN FLOOR(rn / 2) = 1 THEN Name END) AS Name1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN FLOOR(rn / 2) = 2 THEN Name END) AS Name3
FROM cte
GROUP BY
    rn % 2
ORDER BY
    rn % 2;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

This approach has an advantage over a union in that it can easily be extended to support more rows and columns as you need.